# Fedora 16 to Fedora 17 post-upgrade tasks

Tags: fedora, package-management, upgrade

I have just successfully upgraded from Fedora 16 to Fedora 17 using the Preupgrade tool. One of the post-upgrade steps [suggested here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/upgrade-fedora-16-to-fedora-17-with-preupgrade/) is to "remove unsupported packages".

The guide says to run `package-cleanup --orphans` to obtain a list of said packages and then `yum remove` each one.

Rather than blindly do this I thought I'd check to make sure that this wouldn't unintentionally remove any needed dependencies. For example, `ModemManager-0.5.3.96-1.fc16.x86_64` is the first package in the list. When I run:

```
yum remove ModemManager-0.5.3.96-1.fc16.x86_64
```

I see that it also wants to remove a number of dependencies that look like valid Fedora 17 packages:

```
=======================================================================================
 Package                     Arch     Version                       Repository    Size
=======================================================================================
Removing:
 ModemManager                x86_64   0.5.3.96-1.fc16               @updates/16  952 k
Removing for dependencies:
 NetworkManager              x86_64   1:0.9.4.0-7.git20120403.fc17  @anaconda-0  6.7 M
 NetworkManager-gnome        x86_64   1:0.9.4.0-7.git20120403.fc17  @anaconda-0  1.3 M
 NetworkManager-openconnect  x86_64   0.9.4.0-7.git20120612.fc16    @updates/16  274 k
 NetworkManager-openvpn      x86_64   1:0.9.3.997-1.fc17            @anaconda-0  679 k
 NetworkManager-pptp         x86_64   1:0.9.3.997-1.fc17            @anaconda-0  467 k
 NetworkManager-vpnc         x86_64   1:0.9.3.997-1.fc17            @anaconda-0  474 k
 anaconda                    x86_64   17.29-1.fc17                  @anaconda-0   12 M
 evolution-NetworkManager    x86_64   3.4.1-2.fc17                  @anaconda-0   14 k

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================
Remove  1 Package (+8 Dependent packages)
```

If I do `yum list NetworkManager` I see:

```
Installed Packages
NetworkManager.x86_64         1:0.9.4.0-7.git20120403.fc17        @anaconda-0
Available Packages
NetworkManager.x86_64         1:0.9.6.4-1.fc17                    updates
```

I also notice that none of the dependencies listed by `yum remove` are in the orphaned package list.

- Is it safe for me to go ahead and remove these "orphaned" packages?
- Do I have to remove these orphaned packages (I'm not short on disk space)?

Answer (score 2):

In this case it would be acceptable to use rpm to uninstall those packages

```
#rpm -e ModemManager-0.5.3.96-1.fc16.x86_64 --nodeps
```

After you have removed all of the unwanted packages, clean up the rpm database with the following commands

```
#rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
#rpm –rebuilddb
#yum clean all
#rm -rf /var/cache/yum 
#yum makecache
```

Comment: Thanks. After adjusting my google-fu I found this: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_PreUpgrade and this: http://fedorasolved.org/Members/fenris02/post_upgrade_cleanup which helped. I also discover that doing `yum update` right after the upgrade cleared out virtually all of the packages reported by `package-cleanup --orphans`.

Comment: @midnightsteel, `yum erase package` deletes the package and everything that depends on it, as it should. The `--nodeps` option to rpm tells it _not_ to check for it, and recommending it to newbies is irresponsible. The steps to clean up the RPM database are completely unneeded.